# I need to create an out files out of my hash keys and store a file list to the files based on my keys

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have two files the first one has a number range and a version name, the number range is retrieved from the second file which is consist of a list number. From the second file I am looking for the numbers start in position 11 for 9 char then compare it with my first file "the range file" then print to the screen the name of the version and how many matches.

My first file looks like this

```
imb,folded   ,655575645,827544086
imb,selfmail ,827549192,827572977
```

My second file looks like this

```
0026110795165557564528452972062
0026110795165557648628452974959
0026110795182749420290503162401
0026110795182749566690703875348
0026110795182750564290503365856
0026110795182751155490713282618
0026110795182751819190503415474
0026110795182752054790503331977
0026110795182752888194578410931
0026110795182753115893308242647
0026110795182753522398248322033
0026110795182753601890723246006
0026110795182754156995403760702
0026110795182754174597213102232
0026110795182754408698248770395
0026110795182754919290713221614
0026110795182755128698248922635
0026110795182755566790713334451
0026110795182755669490713213633
0026110795182755806390507009696
0026110795182756204890713212248
0026110795182756217690713273839
0026110795182756259998248961157
0026110795182756309595403769515
0026110795182756708894578164887
0026110795182756829090713282238
0026110795182757082791367220156
0026110795182757130090713274108
0026110795182757297798248934527
0026110795182757370277063564556
```

My output now looks like this

```
folded IMB Count: 15
No Matched IMB Count: 1
selfmail IMB Count: 14
```

I need to create files with a name based on the version name in my first array, then to print to each files the original value for what it match. For instance folded has 15 match I need to print the original number from the file list to a file with a name of `folded.txt`

my code is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings
use strict
use feature qw{ say };

sub trimspaces {
  my @argsarray = @_;
  $argsarray[0] =~ s/^\s+//;
  $argsarray[0] =~ s/\s+$//;
  return $argsarray[0];
}

open(INPUT  , "< D:\\Home\\emahou\\imbfilelist.txt") or die $!;
open(INPUT2 , "< D:\\Home\\emahou\\imbrange.txt") or die $!;

my $n;
my @fh;
my $value;
my @ranges;
my $isMatch;
my $printed;
my $fVersion;
my %versionHash=();

while (<INPUT2>) {
    chomp;

    my ($version, $from, $to) = (split /,/)[ 1, 2, 3 ];
    push @ranges, [ $from, $to, trimspaces($version)];

    if (!exists $versionHash{trimspaces($version)})
    {
      $versionHash{trimspaces($version)}=0;
    }
}

$versionHash{"No Matched"}=0;

close INPUT2;

while (<INPUT>) {
    $isMatch=0;
    $n = substr($_,12-1,9);

    for my $r (@ranges) {
        if ( $n >= $r->[0] && $n <= $r->[1]) {
          $fVersion=$r->[2];

          if (exists $versionHash{$fVersion}) {
            $versionHash{$fVersion}++;
          }

          $isMatch=1;

          last;
        }
    }

    if (!$isMatch) {
      $versionHash{"No Matched"}++;
    }
}

foreach my $key (keys %versionHash) {
  print STDOUT "$key IMB Count: " . $versionHash{$key} . "\n";
}

close INPUT;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do as you ask

It works by building a hash `%filelist` with keys from the second column of `imbfilelist.txt` and values `from`, `to`, `fh` (the output file handle) and `count` (the number of records that matched this range

Then the `imbrange.txt` is read a line at a time, the nine-digit code extracted, and compared with the `from` and `to` values of each element of the `%filelist` hash. If a match is found then the line is printed to the corresponding file handle and the counter is incremented. If the code from this line doesn't match any of the ranges then `$none_matched` is incremented for output in the summary

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

chdir 'D:\Home\emahou';

# Build a hash of `version` strings with their `from` and `to` values

open my $fh, '<', 'imbfilelist.txt';
my %filelist;
while ( <$fh> ) {
  chomp;
  my ($version, $from, $to) = (split /\s*,\s*/)[1,2,3];
  $filelist{$version} = { from => $from, to => $to };
}

# Open an output file for each item and set the count to zero

while ( my ($version, $info) = each %filelist ) {
  open $info->{fh}, '>', "$version.txt";
  $info->{count} = 0;
}

# Filter the data in the range file, printing to the
# appropriate output file and keeping count

open $fh, '<', 'imbrange.txt';
my $none_matched = 0;
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
  next unless $line =~ /\S/;
  chomp $line;
  my $code = substr $line, 11, 9;
  my $matched = 0;
  while ( my ($version, $info) = each %filelist ) {
    next unless $code >= $info->{from} and $code <= $info->{to};
    print { $info->{fh} } $line, "\n";
    ++$info->{count};
    ++$matched;
  }
  ++$none_matched unless $matched;
}

close $_->{fh} for values %filelist;

# Print the summary

while ( my ($version, $info) = each %filelist ) {
   print "$version IMB Count: $info->{count}\n"
}
print "None matched IMB Count: $none_matched\n"
```

**output**

```
selfmail IMB Count: 14
folded IMB Count: 15
None matched IMB Count: 1
```

**folded.txt**

```
0026110795165557564528452972062
0026110795165557648628452974959
0026110795182749420290503162401
0026110795182749566690703875348
0026110795182750564290503365856
0026110795182751155490713282618
0026110795182751819190503415474
0026110795182752054790503331977
0026110795182752888194578410931
0026110795182753115893308242647
0026110795182753522398248322033
0026110795182753601890723246006
0026110795182754156995403760702
0026110795182754174597213102232
0026110795182754408698248770395
```

**selfmail.txt**

```
0026110795182754919290713221614
0026110795182755128698248922635
0026110795182755566790713334451
0026110795182755669490713213633
0026110795182755806390507009696
0026110795182756204890713212248
0026110795182756217690713273839
0026110795182756259998248961157
0026110795182756309595403769515
0026110795182756708894578164887
0026110795182756829090713282238
0026110795182757082791367220156
0026110795182757130090713274108
0026110795182757297798248934527
```

Comment: I am getting errors Use of uninitialized value $version in hash element at D:\Home\emahou\test.pl line 17, <$_[...]> line 1. and it goes to line 30. @Borodin

Comment: @earfriend: Looks like `imbfilelist.txt` isn't as you described it. Please show your real file